# JBoss cant find JDBC driver for PostgreSQL in development environment

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jboss, ejb

Right now, I am doing this EJB tutorial: http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/#heading_toc_j_23 , but instead of GlassFish I use JBoss 7.0, and instead of DerbyDB I use PostgreSQL and Hibernate as persistence provider. My problem is, that I can't deploy the EAR and test the webservices (this is where I am in that tutorial ATM), because JBoss gives me following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."JEETutorialEAR.ear/JEETutorialEJB.jar#JEETutorialEJB": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."JEETutorialEAR.ear/JEETutorialEJB.jar#JEETutorialEJB": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: JEETutorialEJB] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:908)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:884)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitService.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.start(PersistenceUnitService.java:77)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver org.postgresql.Driver class not found
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BasicServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(BasicServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BasicServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(BasicServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2253)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2249)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1720)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @624b035d (roots: C:\Users\myname\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:99)
    ... 23 more
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JEETutorialEJB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jeetutorial"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="jeetutorial"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have PostgreSQL JDBC driver added in project path. And I did, what is advised here: http://jan.zawodny.pl/blog/2011/07/jboss-7-postgresql-9 sans datasource configuration (I guess that is done by Eclipse during starting-up the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually deploy the driver e.g. in standalone mode by copying it into 
$JBOSS/standalone/deployments/ . There is no need to package it as a module.

In future versions of AS7.1 it will be possible to use the classical -ds.xml files again for creating datasources. But that is only a comment :)

Comment: Well, I just did what you said, and it worked. But I couldn't figure out, how to access EJB's webservices mentioned later in that tutorial, so i switched to Glassfish server.